python function set value according to master dataframe
I need to define a function that, depending on the value of the input variable and a master dataframe, the function assigns the return value according to a master dataframe.
This is the master (df_master) dataframe the function has to recieve and, depending on it and the input value, return value:



value (from)
value (until)
value to return




0
30
1


31
50
2


51
100
3



For example, if input value = 10, return 1
For example, if input value = 90, return 3
...
The function should be something like:
def assing_value (input_var, df_master):
    ...


Try:
def assing_value(input_var, df_master):
    idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
        df_master["value (from)"], df_master["value (until)"], closed="both"
    )
    mask = idx.contains(input_var)
    
    return df_master[mask]["value to return"].squeeze()


print(assing_value(10, df))

Prints:
1

